# Invert specific pages of a PDF

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

Is there an easy way to only invert certain page numbers in a PDF? These are scanned in documents, which are essentially images saved into a PDF format.

The problem is that certain pages are white text on black background. Adobe Acrobat does not seem to offer this feature. I have tried with Irfanview although you have to save after EVERY page you change. Not convenient if I have to edit a 100 page PDF.

I found this useful imagemagick trick, although it will only output the pages you specify to out.pdf. I need to have the final result include all pages back into one PDF: http://blog.dillfrog.com/how-to-invert-a-pdf-using-imagemagick/

I only want to edit a few pages in a large multipage document, and save the output back into a full, single, pdf document. Adobe photoshop allows you to edit PDFs, although you can only save the output to a single page, not back to a multipage PDF....

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help you but maybe [PDF Architect Professional](http://www.pdfarchitect.org/download) is what you are looking for. It can insert backgrounds

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the "inverted" PDF, you can use a PDF printer like PDFcreator to create a new PDF taking the correct set of pages from one or another PDF and merge them into only one PDF.

When you're printing in PDF, you choose to put into the queue.
Once you have put everything in queue, in PDFCreator, you can right-click and select "merge all" and finally print only one PDF file.

Take care to put your pages in queue in the correct order

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Linux, you could extract the necessary pages from the big PDF using [PDF Mod](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/PdfMod), use any method that works for you to invert the colors for those extracted pages, then use PDF Mod once more to reinsert the pages and re-save the big PDF. A bit of manual work, but it should work.